# Resetting the fields to null value when fileds not visible

Tags: javascript, html

This is a conditional script which show a block of field if a certain answer is selected, in this case a Yes.

**HTML**

```
<form name="theForm">
  Have you attended college?<br>
  <input type="radio" name="married" value="yes" onclick="return toggleMe(this, 'marriedInfo')"> Yes
  <input type="radio" name="married" value="no" onclick="return toggleMe2(this, 'marriedInfo')"> No<br>
  <div id="marriedInfo" style="display: none; margin-left: 20px;">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>College name:</td>
        <td style="text-align: right;"><input name="name" type="text"></td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td>Years Attended:</td>
        <td style="text-align: right;"><input name="bday" type="text"></td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td>Degree:</td>
        <td style="text-align: right;"><input name="bplace" type="text"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function toggleMe(obj, a){
  var e=document.getElementById(a);
  if(!e)return true;
    e.style.display="block"
    return true;
}

function toggleMe2(obj, a){
  var e=document.getElementById(a);
  if(!e)return true;
  e.style.display="none";
  return true;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lctnmkhq/)

When yes selected, a block of html fields is shown and the user can proceed further to fill out.

How do I reset the value of these fields to null if a user decides not move ahead after filling the first field (if he hits no the block disappears but the value already entered stays).

I tried using the e.reset() but the whole script stops working. e = document.getelementbyid()

Comment: You can add the code snippet here so it can be run without opening the fiddle. There is a button for that in the editor.

Comment: Note that I removed the `jQuery` tag from the question as it's completely irrelevant

Comment: @Esko, sorry, new to Stack.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, thank you. New to stack.

Comment: @Mecom No problem, just educating you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you can select the inputs when you hide them and wipe their `value` property. Try this:

```
function toggleMe2(obj, a) {
  var e = document.getElementById(a);
  if (!e) 
    return true;

  e.style.display = "none";
  document.querySelector('input[name="name"]').value = '';
  document.querySelector('input[name="bday"]').value = '';
  document.querySelector('input[name="bplace"]').value = '';
  return true;
}
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lctnmkhq/1/)

Comment: But why doesn't the reset work? If I have lot more fields (say 10-15) then setting the values each to ' ' wouldn't be a pretty job.

Comment: That's because the `marriedinfo` element is a `div`. You need to call `reset()` on the `form`

Comment: hmm, I'll need to search more about it. Thank you for answering and accepting.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this to your code

```
var t = e.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (index = 0; index < t.length; ++index) {
  t[index].value = "";
}
```

[**Your updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lctnmkhq/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Since JQuery has been tagged, you can do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("[name='married'][value='no']").click(function() {
    $("#marriedInfo").find("input").each(function() {
      $(this).val("");
    });
  });
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/ccddtkza/)

Answer (score 0):

You can paste the below code inside your toggleMe2 function after e.style.display="none"

```
  var container = document.getElementById(a);

  var inputs = container.getElementsByTagName('input');

  for (var index = 0; index < inputs.length; ++index) {
        inputs[index].value = '';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use reset, but you need to properly get the form node. You need to use the id attribute for your form. For example, the id can be theForm:

```
<form id="theForm">
```

Then, you can invoke reset in the toggleMe function.

```
function toggleMe(obj, a) {
  var e = document.getElementById(a);
  if (!e) return true;
  document.getElementById("theForm").reset();
  e.style.display = "block"
  return true;
}
```

This will work. However, the radio button will never be selected. As a way to overcome this, you need to move the radio buttons out of your form element. For example:

```
Have you attended college?
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="married" value="yes" onclick="return toggleMe(this, 'marriedInfo')"> Yes
  <input type="radio" name="married" value="no" onclick="return toggleMe2(this, 'marriedInfo')"> No
  <br>

<form id="theForm">
```